# algorithm to "explode" mesh

Tags: 3d, 3d-meshes

i have a simple triangle mesh which i want to explode.
so i am looking for an algorithm that makes every triangle to move outwards from the centerpoint. 
is there already something premade like this?

thanks!

Comment: You're looking for particle systems, there's a great deal of material on that, can't give you any links off the top of my head though. Furthermore, if your models are made of too coarse a mesh, you'll need to look into tessellation and subdivision techniques to blow up larger patches of your mesh.

Comment: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/shatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check this out:

http://www.cgafaq.info/wiki/Half_edge_general

http://en.nicoptere.net/?p=960

Comment: Unfortunately links are down

Answer (score 4):

Look into [particle physics](http://www.gamasutra.com/resource_guide/20030121/jacobson_01.shtml). Each vertex would be set up as one particle per triangle it is a part of and each would be pushed away from the explosion point using whatever force you want. To keep the triangles from warping as the particles move, add stick constraints for each edge (they're described in the article linked above). When the constraints are resolved, it will modify the particle movement and cause the triangles to move independently, flipping and rotating as they go.